# In 2021, does anything beat pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, luatex

It's 2021.

I want to write a book in LaTeX, no restrictions from any publishers. I do not want to write packages.

I read the terms LaTeX3 (now part of LaTeX itself?), XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, ..., but actually I have no idea what superseded what or if these are all different forks that progress independently.

Is there anything I gain from NOT using pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Fonts: Unicode/system fonts are available in xelatex/lualatex. Access to internals: lua code in lualatex.

Comment: The question in the title and the one in the text are not quite the same. Does anything beat pdftex? Sure, luatex can do more. But if you don't specifically need its features, then there is no gain at all in using it. Rather drawbacks.

Comment: for the most part the input for pdflatex lualatex and xelatex are the same so you don't have to choose in advance. Your font choice may lead you to luatex or xelatex (if you want to use system fonts, or non latin characters) but otherwise just use whichever you prefer

Comment: You should probably change the title though as that is open to closing the question as "Opinion based"  Some people might say Word, or indesign or ...

Comment: @campa really depends on your definition of "beating", speed wise, pdfTeX is pretty far ahead of LuaTeX and XeTeX. Feature wise you're right, LuaTeX is the leading player here.

Comment: @Skillmon That's precisely what I meant with "drawbacks". Should've been less cryptic...

Comment: This is about to be deleted because of the way the question is phrased.  Please change it so something like "In 2021, what do other flavors of LaTeX provide that pdfLaTeX doesn't?"

Answer (score 5):

You wrote,

> It's 2021. I want to write a book in LaTeX. ... Is there anything I gain from NOT using pdfLaTeX?

I think the answer ultimately depends on how you define the term **LaTeX**. If you restrict the term to be functionally equivalent to pdfLaTeX, i.e., the joining of the pdftex *engine* and the LaTeX2e *format*, and if you thus choose not to talk about the capabilities of the xetex and luatex engines, then you might as well as write your document in a way that makes it compilable under pdfLaTeX. (Of course, these days many documents that compile just fine under pdfLaTeX will also compile just fine under LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Conversely, if you do intend to talk about the capabilities of the xetex and luatex engines -- and, frankly, why *wouldn't* you? After all, it's 2021... -- and if you intend to provide some practical examples of code that makes use of the additional capabilities of XeTeX and/or LuaTeX, you've just given yourself permission NOT to use pdfLaTeX...

Answer (score 4):

If you have a choice of what engine to use, I would recommend LuaLaTeX.  That has better support for modern fonts, OpenType features, and all the world’s languages than any other engine.  It lets you use a much broader repertoire of math symbols and alphabets than is possible in PDFLaTeX.  It also supports some packages that I think improve the appearance of a document considerably, such as `microtype` font expansion with Unicode fonts.  But if you did want to use a legacy 8-bit math font, you still can.

Comment: My memory may be failing me here, but I believe that pdfLaTeX does support `microtype`; that's one of the features highlighted in Thanh's dissertation. https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-4/tb69thanh.pdf

Comment: @BarbaraBeeton I think Davislor means that microtype is available for lualatex, I don't remember if it works with xelatex

Comment: @daleif --  Oh, I agree that LuaLaTeX provides more than pdfLaTeX, but this formulation seems to imply that pdfLaTeX is lacking the feature that's highlighted in the title of the dissertation.  (I don't remember about XeTeX either.)

Comment: @BarbaraBeeton that is not how I read their answer. I don't read any negatives in it

Comment: @daleif -- I'm sure it wasn't intentional.  (But I always seem to read things in the most misunderstandable way.  Maybe that's why I've been moderately successful as an editor.)

Comment: @daleif Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. I’ve changed the wording to specify what combination of features only LuaLaTeX supports.

Comment: LuaLaTeX has some show-stopping issues though. For example, it won't break after en- and em-dashes, whether they're input TeX-style as --/--- or as Unicode characters –/—. pdfLaTeX breaks after TeX-style inputs but not Unicode input while XeLaTeX breaks after either.

Comment: @Davislor but the default behavior is wrong. That really should not be considered acceptable. The correct definition, incidentally, would be `\penalty\exhyphenpenalty` rather than `{\hspace 0pt}`.

Comment: And the `\hspace` before the dash is also wrong. MacOS breaks lines before em dashes which makes me sad and angry on a nearly daily basis. Eventually, people will start to think that it's an acceptable breakpoint and they'd be wrong (the Tschicholdian practice of replacing em dashes with space-en dash-space assumes that the first space is a non-breaking space, but I've seen recently typeset books that get that wrong also. None of the Tschichold-era Penguin paperbacks commit such a heinous sin).

Comment: @DonHosek I don’t disagree with you that the default behavior is wrong.  Thanks for the better fix!